# laravel eloquent repository query foreign key tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

hi i am using a custom repository and I am getting comfortable with querying one table to retrieve data like so:

```
public function getAll()
{
// get all logged in users projects order by project name asc and paginate 9 per page
return \Auth::user()->projects()->orderBy('project_name', 'ASC')->paginate(9);
```

}

and in my controller I simply call

```
public function __construct(ProjectRepositoryInterface $project) {

    $this->project = $project;

}

public function index()
    {
        $projects = $this->project->getAll();
        echo View::make('projects.index', compact('projects'));         
    }
```

and my view is as so:

```
@if (Auth::check())
 @if (count($projects) > 0)
@foreach ($projects as $project)
{{ $project->project_name }}
 @endforeach 
 @else
  <p>No records, would you like to create some...</p>
@endif
 {{ $projects->links; }}
 @endif
```

However within my projects table I have a status_id and a client_id and I want to retrieve records of this these tables with the logged in user but I am not sure how to structure my query, does anyone have any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

According to the laravel [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships), In your project model you can add the following function:

```
class Project extends Eloquent
{
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Client::class);
    }
}
```

In your client model you can then add the inverse of the relationship with the function:

```
class Client extends Eloquent
{
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve the data with a function like:

```
$clients = Project::find(1)->clients;
```